# Java generics on method

Tags: java, generics, methods

Might be a dumb question but I would like to ask how to make this possible in Java. I have an interface that has a method with the following signature

```
public <ComponentType> void attachFacilitiesTable(ComponentType comp);
```

On my concrete implementation I would like override it to something like:

```
public void attachFacilitiesTable(Node comp);
```

Thanks

Regards,
Ezekiel

Comment: Make the interface (not just the attach method) generic, then you can pass any `<ComponentType>` you like.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, ComponentType is a base class, and Node is something that extends it?

If it is so, then I think this is the syntax you are looking for:

```
public <T extends ComponentType> void attachFacilitiesTable(T comp);
```

This way, you say, T is a generic type that must extend from ComponentType.

Your example is equivalent to

```
public <T> void attachFacilitiesTable(T comp);
```

Where T is a type, without any restrictions. You are just using a different "variable" name, which, although named ComponentType, doesn't have anything to do with the class named ComponentType.

Comment: Hi daShader, the ComponentType is just a representation for type such as T,K,E,V in <T>, <K,V>, <E>.

Comment: Oh, in that case, I don't think you can have the implementation take anything by ComponentType. Your implementation basically needs to accept any type (because ComponentType can be anything).

Generics are just for compile time check. Once code is compiled, they are simply removed (this process is called type erasure)

And

public <ComponentType> void attachFacilitiesTable(ComponentType comp);

Becomes:

public void attachFacilitiesTable(Object comp);

Comment: I see. Thanks daShader!